# the count of the UINavigationController's viewControllers will be 0 after you call popViewController

Tags: ios

I have three UIViewControllers, so I use the UINavigationController as the rootViewController of the window. As I log the count of [navigationController.viewControllers count] I found that the count will be 0 when you call the popViewControllerAnimated. The weird thing is that you log the count when you back to the previous ViewController, the count is going to be normal, the actual count of the controller on the stack. what does the popViewController do to make such a strange thing?

Answer (score 0):

When you pop the third view controller, its `navigationController` property is `nil` so getting its `viewControllers` will return `nil` and `count` will return 0.

Comment: From the wording of the question I would have assumed that the OP was not using the navigationController property of any of those viewControllers but directly the instance he added as a rootViewController.

Comment: @Till I didn't pay attention to that. For now I'll leave my answer and I'll delete/edit it when Danyun gives more details.